# extracting value out of NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a NSDictionary called data and when I print using NSLog it gives me:

```
DATA IS {
    aps =     {
        alert = "aherlambang liked your photo";
        badge = 1;
    };
    "media_id" = "220516456473412852_29088696";
}
```

I tried to extract the media_id by doing:

```
 NSLog(@"DATA IS %@ MEDIA ID IS %@", userInfo, [userInfo valueForKey:@"media-id"]);
```

but it always gives me null. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key in the data is `"media_id"`, and you're trying to use the key `"media-id"`.

Change `"media-id"` to `"media_id"` and you should be able to read your dictionary.

```
 NSLog(@"DATA IS %@ MEDIA ID IS %@", userInfo, [userInfo valueForKey:@"media_id"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because your dictionary is named data and your accessing userIfno?